# How to upload a file using Django and Google App Engine Blobstore API

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-admin

I have an app I am developing using:

- Django 1.5
- Google App Engine
- Google Cloud SQL
- Python 2.7.5

As using Cloud SQL I am using the pure Django not the no-rel version making full use of the Django ORM.

In the admin part of the app I want to have a form to upload a csv file using GAE Blobstore API.

What I want to achieve is the uploading of the file to the Blobstore and the Blob Key referencing this uploaded file to be saved in my model.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not uploading the file as part of a Django form, you can manually handle the uplaod as per BlobStore instructions, then fetch the BlobKey, and save it as a string in your Django model.  That's probably the most straighforward way to go.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

Another option is to take the storage component in djangoappengine (designed for Django-nonrel), and adapt it for use with normal Django.  I don't think there's any reason why this shouldn't work (after you put some effort into adapting it)

https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/blob/master/djangoappengine/storage.py

Comment: Ended up using this as my storage component to achieve this: https://github.com/kienluu/blobstore_storage Thanks for your input.