# Uploading and showing images in django with Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, file-upload

I have been trying to implement ndb.BlobProperty() for my user in django with google app engine.

```
class UserData(ndb.Model):
    email= ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    role = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    blob_key = ndb.BlobProperty()
    serving_url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

In the form, I have :

```
<form  method="POST" action="{{upload_url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="name" type="text">
        <input name="role" type="text">
        <input name="profile_photo" type="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="submit">
</form>
```

I am trying to upload using this code.

```
upload_files = str(request.FILES['profile_photo'])
u = UserData(email = user.email(),name=name,role=role)
if upload_files:
    u.blob_key=upload_files
    u.serving_url = images.get_serving_url(u.blob_key)
u.put()
```

And in my template, I am trying to show the image of the user.

```
<img src="{{people.profile_photo}}"></img>
<img src="{{people.get_serving_url}}"></img>
```

And both of them raises a 404 error.

I have already referred these sources, but none of them worked.

- [Django on Google App Engine: cannot upload images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014147/django-on-google-app-engine-cannot-upload-images)
- [How to upload a file using Django and Google App Engine Blobstore API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303539/how-to-upload-a-file-using-django-and-google-app-engine-blobstore-api)
- [How to upload a file using Django and Google App Engine Blobstore API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303539/how-to-upload-a-file-using-django-and-google-app-engine-blobstore-api)
- [How to upload file in django google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731546/how-to-upload-file-in-django-google-app-engine)
- [Google App Engine (Python) - Uploading a file (image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392779/google-app-engine-python-uploading-a-file-image)
- [Image Upload in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381238/image-upload-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: take a look at [pyuploadcare](https://github.com/uploadcare/pyuploadcare). it has django model for image uploads.

Comment: That's okay. But, pyuploadcare is for django models(I think so). But, in my case, I am using ndb.Model to store my data. Can you be specific about how can I use pyuploadcare with my exisiting model(if there exist any possible solution).

Comment: sorry about that! if you'll take a look at django's Uploadcare field , you'll see that this is in fact TextField, as only uploaded file URL is saved to DB.